# Ruby instance variables versus ActiveRecord attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've read that ruby objects are just places where we can store instance variables (and class pointers). So:

```
class Person
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end
```

Now if we run:

```
p = Person.new(101)
```

Then we get:

```
#<Person:0x86cf5b8 @age=101>
```

Great, the property **age** is stored as an *instance variable*, as expected. But things work a little differently if we convert the model to inherit from ActiveRecord. Now, after instantiating an new Person, we see this:

```
# timestamps removed
#<Person id: 1, age: 101 >
```

The *age* property no longer appears to be an instance variable. So what is really going on here?

I know that we can access the `@attributes` instance variable, which contains a hash of all the properties and values, so I'm wondering if ActiveRecord is possibly modifying the console output to present the objects attributes in this way.

Is it possible to instantiate a Ruby object where properties are held as attributes and not instance variables, without using ActiveRecord?

Comment: What an "attribute" vs "instance variable" in a non-AR class, in your question?

Comment: Dave Thomas stated in a video that objects are just collections of instance variables. Yet ActiveRecord objects do not store their properties as instance variables, so that's a little confusing for me.

Comment: Why? AR object aren't plain Ruby objects, and properties that should be persisted must be differentiated from properties that shouldn't. Other implementation mechanism *could* have been used, but weren't.

Comment: `AR object aren't plain Ruby objects` - thanks, that explains it really. I glossed over a lot of this stuff when I started learning Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can extend a ruby class with `include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods` to expose your instance variables as `ActiveModel`-like attributes.

[See the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods.html) for more information.

Comment: awesome, it's making more sense now

Answer (score 1):

as you see in your code 'storing' properties as instance vars was your own doing, so if you wanna hold them any other way, is also up to you. ruby gives you convenience class methods to define getter and setter methods like attr_accessor.

also worth noting, that if you inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, you should not override initialize.

Comment: Thanks, I took Dave Thomas's words "Objects are just collections of instance variables" as meaning that they can't be anyting else, but I see there's a bit more too it all now.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if ActiveRecord is possibly modifying the console output to present the objects attributes in this way.

Well, kind of. The method responsible for that is `inspect`, and [it's implemented by Object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) in a way that (emplasis mine):

> ...shows the object's class name, an encoding of the object id, and **a list of the instance variables and their values** (by calling inspect on each of them).

There's more right after:

> User defined classes should override this method to provide a better representation of obj.

This is exactly what ActiveRecord does and the reason why you're seeing this output. The overridden method does not list instance variables, but displays AR attributes.

So just because you aren't seeing the instance variable in the console doesn't mean it isn't there!